# AWS Apigateway does have any static IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an aws api gateway which has a custom domain.
I have to access one of client's api from AWS api gateway.
Those api's will be accessible based on IP address.
If I want to access those api's from aws, I need to know the Ip address of my AWS apigateway.
But I am not sure where I can get this.
Any possibilities to get the static IP address of AWS apigateway?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you need to access a client's API from API Gateway? Do you mean you are using API Gateway to proxy requests to a client's API? Or are you triggering an AWS Lambda function, or an EC2 instance or something with API Gateway, and that Lambda/EC2 instance needs to access the client's API?

Comment: MarkB: I am triggering a lambda function from AWS, which will calls the external API.The external Api restricts based on the IP address.So If I know the IP Address from where it gets triggered, then client will allow that particular Ip address.

Comment: So the question isn't about static IP for API Gatway at all, the question is about static IP for AWS Lambda. The part about "knowing the IP address from where it gets triggered" makes no sense, because that has no bearing on the IP address the Lambda function will use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the API Gateway doesn't support this scenario of invoking an IP-whitelisted API directly. Basically any AWS instance can be used to make the API call and there's many IPs that AWS is using for this.

There are some ways around this, depending on your situation;

- If the server you are reaching is within your own VPC, you could create a VPC link (with NLB) and circumvent the IP-whitelist issue. This solution only works for resources within your control.
- If the server is external and is expecting a static IP, your best solution is to make your call from within a VPC. To make sure you have a static public IP you can use an elastic IP and a NAT Gateway in your VPC ([more info here](http://www.studytrails.com/amazon-aws/aws-vpc-tutorial-part-iii/)). 
  To invoke the external API triggered from the API Gateway you can use a Lambda but because of the VPC a cold start will be quite slow, >10s. To make sure the API will be responding fast you can use an EC2 instance or ECS service on Fargate.

Comment: Bram:Thanks for your response. My server is external which needs static IP address. I am trying to access the external server api from my VPC only.I have Nat gateway already in my VPC.There I have private IP address.Is that one will be a static one?

Comment: To reach an external server you will need/use a public IP. By default this IP is not static, but if you use an elastic IP it will be.

Comment: "you could create a VPC link (with NLB) and circumvent the IP-whitelist issue"  Doesn't this still leave your server open to requests from elsewhere in your VPC?

Answer (score 1):

After you clarified your requirements in the comments above it appears that you need your AWS Lambda function, which is being triggered by API Gateway, to appear to a third party as if it has a static outgoing IP address.

The solution to this is to configure your Lambda function to run in your VPC, in a private subnet of your VPC that has a route to a NAT Gateway. Then all outgoing connections from the Lambda function which access resources outside your VPC will use the NAT Gateway's static IP address.